# Find Max/Min Arbitrary Priority

Tags: t-sql, refactoring

I'm trying to aggregate rows based on a max or min value, where max/min is determined by a business rule rather than by inherent value.  In other words, I need to create a custom max/min - without using the CLR.  I have a working self-contained example in the snippet below, but I feel there must be a simpler way.

In this particular case, I need the business priority of an IPA column to be defined by the [Seq] value shown in the [IPAMap] CTE below.  I then take an arbitrary set of rows from the [TestData] table/cte (having only four rows in this sample), and aggregate them into two rows that have the proper IPA values selected, based on priority.

```
--Table [IPAMap] holds all possible values for [IPA], and reflects the relative
--'priority' of each with the [Seq] column.  This table is used as a lookup for
--business rules.
;WITH IPAMap (Seq, IPA) AS ( 
SELECT 1, 'Q' UNION ALL 
SELECT 2, 'S' UNION ALL 
SELECT 3, 'A' UNION ALL 
SELECT 4, 'L'
) 
--Table [TestData] represents the real data. 
, TestData (CustomerID, IPA) AS ( 
SELECT '123', 'A' UNION ALL 
SELECT '123', 'S' UNION ALL 
SELECT '234', 'L' UNION ALL 
SELECT '234', 'Q' 
) 
--Table [PartyIPASeq] finds the lowest Seq rank from [TestData] 
,PartyIPASeq (CustomerID, IPASeq) AS ( 
 SELECT  
   CustomerID,  
   MIN(IP.Seq) 
 FROM TestData [TD] 
  INNER JOIN IPAMap [IP] ON IP.IPA = TD.IPA 
  GROUP BY CustomerID 
) 
--The final selection provides the key and the 'IPA' with the lowest rank 
SELECT TD.CustomerID, TD.IPA 
FROM TestData [TD] 
 INNER JOIN IPAMap [IP] ON IP.IPA = TD.IPA 
 INNER JOIN PartyIPASeq [SEQ] ON SEQ.CustomerID = [TD].CustomerID 
   AND SEQ.IPASeq = IP.Seq
```

The result of the above query is this:

```
CustomerID  IPA
234         S
123         Q
```

This is correct, but I'm hoping someone can show me an easier way to get the same job done.

Comment: Your `DISTINCT` is redundant. Using `GROUP BY` guarantees that the rows in the result set will be distinct.

Comment: You can use CASE statements inside aggregates,   MIN(CASE MA.IPA WHEN 3 THEN 7 WHEN 4 THEN 6 etc    But I doubt this is much simpler or performant, other than resulting in a slightly simpler execution plan. If the mappings dont change, why not put them into a permanent table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the answer is to use a window function with an order-by of a charindex, like this:

```
WITH TestData (CustomerID, IPA) AS ( 
    SELECT '123', 'A' UNION ALL 
    SELECT '123', 'S' UNION ALL 
    SELECT '234', 'L' UNION ALL 
    SELECT '234', 'Q' 
    ) 
SELECT CustomerID, IPA
FROM (
        SELECT CustomerID, 
        IPA, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CustomerID ORDER BY CHARINDEX(IPA, 'QSAL')) rownum
        FROM TestData
    ) A
WHERE rownum = 1
```

If the business data uses multi-character values, then the CHARINDEX is replaced with a PATINDEX function.